# Subfigure vertically (!!! not side by side)

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I have two PDF figures. I would like to combine them to make one figure with sub-figures `(a)` and `(b)` so that they appear vertically (figure `(a)` is on top of figure `(b)`), NOT side-by-side because my document has 1 column. I found only for side-by-side. Using package `subcaption` I tried as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[trim=70 30 90 60,clip,width=\textwidth]{FigA.pdf}
\caption{Figure A}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[trim=70 30 90 60,clip,width=\textwidth]{FigureB.pdf}
\caption{Figure B}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption}
\end{figure}
```

However, although the figures appear vertically, the figure `(b)` intersect the caption of the figure `(a)`. If there is no other way to organize them, how can I add space between them?

[image: That's how they appear]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I try to compile your code using some placeholder images I can not reproduce the overlap.

Comment: Did you try with a blank line in front of the second `\begin{subfigure}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *will* get the two subfigures stacked vertically with the code you present, because the space after the first `\end{subfigure}` allows for a line break.

However, a blank line and some additional vertical space will provide some separation.

In the code I had to add `height=8cm` in order to not exceed the page dimensions. Your images are probably much less tall. In any case, such big float should have a `p` option, or it might block the float queue.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[trim=70 30 90 60,clip,width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure A}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[trim=70 30 90 60,clip,width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure B}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Main caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]